# GTK3 : Critical error on "g_signal_connect_data"

Tags: c, xml, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I have tried to reproduce "example-4.c" of GTK tutorial describe here : https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/getting_started.html

A simple example using XML description of UI + some c code. Instead using GTK4, I used GTK3 and so, compiling with :

```
gcc `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0` exemple4.c -o hello `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Both **exemple4.c** and **builder.ui** (xml like file) are in the same folder.

Main window pop up but empty and I get the following errors (two time):

```
(hello:19840): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 19:38:31.985: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(hello:19840): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:38:31.985: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(hello:19840): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 19:38:31.985: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(hello:19840): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:38:31.985: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

I guess that it's something simple related to the two buttons but I miss why.

Here after the content of the two files :
**exemple4.c**:

```
#include <gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib/gstdio.h>

static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static void
quit_cb (GtkWindow *window)
{
  gtk_window_close (window);
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  /* Construct a GtkBuilder instance and load our UI description */
  GtkBuilder *builder = gtk_builder_new ();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "builder.ui", NULL);

  /* Connect signal handlers to the constructed widgets. */
  GObject *window = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window");
  gtk_window_set_application (GTK_WINDOW (window), app);

  GObject *button = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "button1");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);

  button = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "button2");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);

  button = gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "quit");
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (quit_cb), window);

  gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET (window));

  /* We do not need the builder any more */
  g_object_unref (builder);
}

int
main (int   argc,
      char *argv[])
{
#ifdef GTK_SRCDIR
  g_chdir (GTK_SRCDIR);
#endif

  GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);

  int status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

and the **builder.ui** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <object id="window" class="GtkWindow">
    <property name="title">Grid</property>
    <child>
      <object id="grid" class="GtkGrid">
        <child>
          <object id="button1" class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">Button 1</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="column">0</property>
              <property name="row">0</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object id="button2" class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">Button 2</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="column">1</property>
              <property name="row">0</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object id="quit" class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label">Quit</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="column">0</property>
              <property name="row">1</property>
              <property name="column-span">2</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found why : **builder.ui** seems broke. I create a similar UI with **glade**. And it works without error.
Here the new UI I generate :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <!-- n-columns=3 n-rows=3 -->
      <object class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button1</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left-attach">0</property>
            <property name="top-attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button2</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left-attach">1</property>
            <property name="top-attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="quit">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">quit</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives-default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left-attach">2</property>
            <property name="top-attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
        <child>
          <placeholder/>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```